# Posição da lista do AutoComplete

Tags: android

Como posicionar a lista do AutoCompleteTextView abaixo do mesmo?, tenho visto alguns tutoriais e simplesmente a lista inicia abaixo mais a minha fica no topo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/actViewEqp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:completionThreshold="2"
    android:dropDownHeight="200dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="ID do equipamento" />
```

Comment: Robson, se a resposta abaixo lhe ajudou a resolver o problema, não acha que seria interessante validá-la como aceita? Ou você também pode votar positivamente nela, caso ela tenha ajudado a chegar numa outra solução tambem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Por padrão a lista de opções do `AutoCompleteTextView` se posiciona abaixo da *view* caso tenha espaço suficiente. Caso isso não aconteça, vai fazer exatamente o que está acontecendo contigo.

A propriedade `android:dropDownHeight="200dp"` define exatamente qual será o a altura básica sua lista suspensa. Se você definir esse tamanho de `200dp`, ele procurará um espaço equivalente a baixo para mostrar o conteúdo da lista, caso contrário, seu comportamento não será mesmo como esperado, fazendo com que apareça acima da *view*.

É possível regular esse tamanho para que seja apenas `50dp`, por exemplo, fazendo com que mostre menos opções para o usuário, porém isso obriga a preencher mais campo de texto. É também possível que senha um tamanho flexível, caso você usa a propriedade `wrap_content`. Isso irá fazer com que sua lista suspensa ocupe o tamanho minimo possível baseado no seu conteúdo.

Leia mais detalhes [aqui na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:dropDownHeight).

Comment: Removi estas configurações do xml e o componente por si só "achou" o seu lugar, vou atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Você ainda tem alguma dúvida? Resolveu seu problema?